# Notify when end of inner div is reached on scrolling outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divs inside an outer div which has scroll bars. I can get the alert when the end of outer div is reached on scrolling but i want to get the alert when end of each inner div is reached.

The html structure is something as follows.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
     <div id = "outer" style= "width:200px;height:200px; overflow:auto;">
         <div id = "#1" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
         <div id = "#2" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
         <div id = "#3" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
         <div id = "#4" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to get notifications when ends of divs #1,#2,#3,#4 are reached and scroll bars are attached to outer div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try any script ... if you did then plz show .....

Comment: I have tried [viewport] (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport), but the viewport here is the window and not the outer div.

Comment: @Anshuma I believe you forgot to close `<div id="outer">`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
 <div id = "outer" style="width:200px;height:200px; overflow:auto;">
     <div id = "#1" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#2" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#3" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#4" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#5" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#6" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#7" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#8" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#9" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#10" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#11" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
     <div id = "#12" class = "inner"> blah blah </div>
 </div>​
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#outer').bind('scroll', function()
    {
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
      {
        alert('end reached');
      }
    })
  }
);​
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3MW/

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is always better to use `console.log('end reached')` than alerts. rather than that, it should be the accepted answer for simplicity & Jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var outerHeightDiv = [], sumHeight = 0;
            $('#outer').find('.inner').each(function (i) {
                sumHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                outerHeightDiv.push(sumHeight);
            });

            $('#outer').scroll(function () {
                var scrollTopHeight = $(this).scrollTop();
                var indexNo = $.inArray(scrollTopHeight, outerHeightDiv);
                //$('#Result').text('Innner div id is:' + indexNo + ' ' + scrollTopHeight + ' ' + outerHeightDiv.join(',')).show();
                if (indexNo > -1) {
                    $('#Result').text('Innner div id is:' + $('#outer .inner:eq(' + indexNo + ')').attr('id')).fadeIn(600).fadeOut(600);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="Result" style="color: Red; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; display: none;">
    </span>
    <div id="outer" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <div id="#1" class="inner">
            blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah
            ----------------------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div id="#2" class="inner">
            blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blah ----------------------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div id="#3" class="inner">
            blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            ----------------------------------------------------
        </div>
        <div id="#4" class="inner">
            blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah blah blah blah
            blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah
            ----------------------------------------------------
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all Thanks. Appreciate ur reply. The code is working fine for only first div.